ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer
I am trying to display the real time data of a instrument which is communicating through serial port with baud rate of 9600. The system is streaming data every 1 min, and some time not streaming for 5 minutes.
I have written the code and its working but sum time is not working due to error:
ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer.
I have tried following code:
import serial
import time
import keyboard
from itertools import islice
import csv
from drawnow import *
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

BC880 = []

def makeFig():
       plt.plot(BC880, 'ko', label='Black Carbon Conc. (ng m-3)')
       plt.legend(loc='upper left')

Ser = serial.Serial('COM5')
while True:
      res = Ser.readline()
      decoded_bytes = res.decode('utf-8')
      AE33data = islice(decoded_bytes.split(","), 11)
      list_AE33data = list(AE33data)
      print(list_AE33data)
      with open("AE33_data.csv","a") as f:
               writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
               writer.writerow(list_AE33data)

      BC = int(list_AE33data[8])
      BC880.append(BC)
      drawnow(makeFig)

Ser.close()
print('Serial Port Disconnected')

I am getting following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AML/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/test.py", line 30, in
drawnow(makeFig)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\drawnow\drawnow.py", line 72, in drawnow
plt.clf()
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1195, in clf
gcf().clear()
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1088, in gcf
return figure()
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1022, in figure
manager = new_figure_manager(
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 545, in new_figure_manager
return _get_backend_mod().new_figure_manager(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3521, in new_figure_manager
return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3526, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
return cls.FigureCanvas.new_manager(figure, num)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1811, in new_manager
return cls.manager_class.create_with_canvas(cls, figure, num)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends_backend_tk.py", line 479, in create_with_canvas
with _restore_foreground_window_at_end():
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in enter
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\AML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends_backend_tk.py", line 43, in _restore_foreground_window_at_end
foreground = _c_internal_utils.Win32_GetForegroundWindow()
ValueError: PyCapsule_New called with null pointer

Expected data printing and plotting by code in real time:
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:06"', ' 635', ' 656', ' 557', ' 554', ' 484', ' 431', ' 419', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:07"', ' -40', ' 45', ' 146', ' 6', ' -37', ' -97', ' -56', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:08"', ' 1086', ' 1089', ' 862', ' 843', ' 777', ' 809', ' 765', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:09"', ' 996', ' 909', ' 1013', ' 890', ' 801', ' 800', ' 871', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:10"', ' 1441', ' 1387', ' 1219', ' 1219', ' 1162', ' 1158', ' 1113', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:11"', ' 735', ' 796', ' 679', ' 624', ' 535', ' 545', ' 501', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:12"', ' 503', ' 493', ' 504', ' 509', ' 395', ' 305', ' 359', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:13"', ' 326', ' 366', ' 259', ' 153', ' 173', ' 132', ' 148', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:14"', ' 746', ' 705', ' 753', ' 673', ' 538', ' 594', ' 591', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:15"', ' 759', ' 859', ' 673', ' 756', ' 599', ' 643', ' 566', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:16"', ' 1247', ' 1236', ' 1163', ' 1019', ' 1059', ' 955', ' 1025', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:17"', ' 1650', ' 1438', ' 1438', ' 1441', ' 1331', ' 1391', ' 1420', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:18"', ' 1021', ' 980', ' 919', ' 942', ' 801', ' 896', ' 773', ' 3.0']
['0683', '"06-Jun-24"', '"15:19"', ' 816', ' 863', ' 930', ' 749', ' 687', ' 629', ' 688', ' 3.0']



this is a known bug and will be fixed with the next version of matplotlib, there is a quick fix, see Github link

Had the same problem and fixed it by upgrading matplotlib to v3.9.1.
pip install matplotlib --upgrade

